# Pressing Back button that I created

Tags: codeigniter

Please cek this back button to return to the previous page:

```
 <?php $gallery_id = $this->uri->segment(3); ?>
<button type="button" class="delete"  onclick="location.href = '<?php echo site_url('cpages/viewpicture/'.$gallery_id); ?>';">BACK</button>
```

If you click "BACK" button instead of showing the correct view it start showing errors:

404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

I wonder why?

What's the difference between that and the normal view?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="btntest" type="button" onclick="return btntest_onclick()" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function btntest_onclick() 
{
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
</script>
```

Try calling a function to your onclick.